# sfGuardAuthentication Error / Login Issue

Tags: php, mysql, validation, authentication, symfony-1.4

Problem:

ALL users cannot login to live frontend web application.  When using known 'valid' login credentials, no validation 'invalid' error feedback is given, it simply returns the user to the login page and denies access.  When using known 'invalid' credentials, the app does provide the correct 'invalid' validation error feedback.

Background:

One day users were able to login without incident, the next day all users (including super-admin users) were unable to login to the live website.  Before incident, website had been up and running for well over 24 months with no login issues.

Also, passwords are hashed using sha1 and salted in the database.  I have a lot of members, and asking members to re-register is to be avoided at all costs (assuming I can even get a super admin to be able to login).

Setup:

Symfony 1.4, PHP 5.4, MySQL, Plugins used: Doctrine Guard, ForkedDoctrineApply

Troubleshooting:

1. Incident appeared to have happened around about the time a scheduled upgrade on the host server from PHP 5.X to PHP 5.4. But I can't be certain. After the automatic upgrade took place, and the problem arose, the host was reverted back to the original PHP version and the login issue remained.  Can I rule out a problem with the host PHP version??
2. Using control panel and symfony commands [symfony guard:create-user], I created a new user, which I verified as successful in the database.  I then tried logging in with the newly-made credentials and the problem persists.
3. Used the registration form on the frontend and attempted to register a new user that way.  No dice.  User is not created.
4. Placed the following code on the template to verify authentication:

   ```
   <?php if (($sf_user->isAuthenticated ())): ?>
      Authenticated
   <?php endif; ?>
   ```

   Under no circumstance was I able to get "Authenticated" to print

Thoughts:

Since I am unable to get a validation error using know valid credentials (it just redirect to the login component without throwing an invalid error), I am led to believe that the credentials are indeed good and valid... I am therefore led to believe that something happened to the authentication process - or I got hacked somehow.

I'm stumped.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the disk space on your server. If it's low there might be problems with creating session data on disk.

Comment: I'm using 12GB out of 1000GB capacity disk.  Don't think that's it.  Can you think of anything else I can look for?

Comment: Then you should make sure if the server has permissions to write to the session folder and if the folder isn't limited by a quota. If it's not this I'm not sure what can be the problem. If there is really no error during validation it seems that the server has problems with saving session data. You can even make some simple tests checking if the session is working (write two simple scripts which use the session and check if it's ok).